# Java reports alias (symlink) as size 0 on Mac OSX. How do I get the true file size?

Tags: java, macos, alias, symlink

```
File file = new File("path to file alias foo");
```

where "path to file alias foo" is an alias reports file size to be 0 instead of the actual file size. I found a workaround to test for aliases:

```
public boolean isLink() {
        try {
            if (file.getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getCanonicalPath())) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.severe(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**EDIT** Actually this code does not work, as pointed out by a poster below. I was trying to adapt a solution from a linux symlink example, but I didn't realize that finder aliases and symlinks were not the same.

**NOT!** this seems to work, but ....

```
file.getCanonicalFile().length();
```

still reports file length to be 0. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Finder aliases are a different beast altogether from normal symbolic links.  The *nix tools on OS X are not aware of aliases at all, because they're stored in the resource fork, I believe.  If you install [`osxutils`](http://osxutils.sourceforge.net/), you can use this shell command to get the target of an alias:

```
hfsdata -e the-alias
```

From Java, I don't know of a better way of doing this other than calling `Runtime.exec(...)`.

Also, I just a did a quick check, and your function for detecting aliases does not work.  AFAICT, Java is not aware of Finder aliases.  If you *really* want to support them, then you'll either need to use something like `osxutils`, or use some platform-specific code to read resource forks (will probably involve JNI).  Neither option is pretty.

If you go the JNI route, check out the [Alias Manager Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html) documentation.  The relevant functions are [`FSIsAliasFile`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSIsAliasFile) and [`FSResolveAliasFile`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSResolveAliasFile).

Comment: Thanks, you saved me some time chasing dead ends. Amazing response time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileRef](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/FileRef.html) Interface from the O'Reilly [Java NIO](http://javanio.info/) API. I believe the getAttribute() method can handle symbolic links as you want, but I have not tried it on Mac OSX. From the [docs](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/FileRef.html):

> The options array may be used to
>   indicate how symbolic links are
>   handled for the case that the file is
>   a symbolic link. By default, symbolic
>   links are followed and the file
>   attribute of the final target of the
>   link is read. If the option
>   NOFOLLOW_LINKS is present then
>   symbolic links are not followed and so
>   the method returns the file attribute
>   of the symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

size = new File(file.getCanonicalPath()).length();

Comment: I believe this would be the same as file.getCanonicalFile().length
it still returns 0.